# Triple DES Encrypting in Python - ECB mode

Tags: python, encryption, des, tripledes

I am trying to send an encrypted plain text to SOAP api to get a response.

The API takes actual text and the encrypted text as input. Below is the code i've and it does return an encrypted text however it doesn't match with o/p from the online tool : https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/triple-des-encrypt-decrypt
The API request works if I use the O/p from the online tool but doesnt if I use the text from python code.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto import Random
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode


key = 'GHYZXFZH2A4B6N6P7R9SPNMT'
cipher_encrypt = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_ECB)
plaintext = 'hellomyf'
encrypted_text = cipher_encrypt.encrypt(plaintext)

ct = b64encode(encrypted_text).decode('utf-8')
print(ct)

byte_string = b64decode(ct)
pt = cipher_encrypt.decrypt(byte_string)
```

```
o/p from script
jqbhxNmunio=
```

```
o/p from tool
jqbhxNmunioWRmE3XhbiHg==
```

I am trying to understand what am I missing in the code why does the length of the online web tool is higher than the length of the text from python code?

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

### Answer

After adding a 8 bit pad like below it did match

```
pad(plaintext.encode('utf-8'), block_size, style='pkcs7')
```

Comment: I suspect that the web site you're visiting is adding some sort of padding to the end of your text.  In ECB mode,  each 8-bytes of text produces 8 bytes of output.

Comment: PyCryptodome does not pad automatically (unlike the online tool using PKCS#7). Padding is supported in a dedicated module [`Crypto.Util.Padding`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module).

Comment: Yep you guys were right! Thank you for the insight, I did add a 8 byte padding and it works now. Thank you for your time.